# Convert Device date and time to PST TimeZone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

As my title say that i need to convert my `iPhone` device date and time to **PST** timezone ?

I got NSDate in NSString formate from server as **PST Timezone**, so i need to convert my current device time to **PST Timezone**.

In my apps. i need to set minimum and maximum time of UIDatePicker such like

minimum time = current time ;
maximum time = Date *(string formate)* which i got it from server.

I use following code

```
NSString *dateString = [[self.listOfDomains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ends_at"]; // got from Server 
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *maxDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    maxDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSCalendar *calMax = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *pstCompoMax = [calMax components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate: maxDate];
    pstCompoMax.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: @"PST"];
    NSDate *pstMaxDate = [calMax dateFromComponents: pstCompoMax];
```

And use it in datePicker

```
[self.datePicker setMinimumDate:pstMinDate];
[self.datePicker setMaximumDate:pstMaxDate];
```

But i can not able to set minimum and maximum date in datePicker.
But if i only set minimum/maximum date of datePicker then it works..

For solve my issue, i'm trying about 2 hour but i can not find any solution.

> **For Your Info :** I'm using Xcode 5 and i need do it in iOS version 5 to Latter (iOS 7)

Please help me on this issue,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the xcode tag as it's not related at all with xcode ;)

Comment: Could you try to make an NSLog of the dateString at the beginning ?

Comment: did you solve your problem.if yes then can you please post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems like setting of NSTimeZone. Could you please try setting the timezone in datepicker like that below:-

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: @"PST"];
```